# PayPal Guest Checkout without paypal account

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I have a prestashop site, with the official PayPal for Europe addon.

I want my customers to be able to pay with their credit card without a paypal account.

What I can see is that PayPal behaves differently for different clients.

For some of them it offers the possibility to Checkout as a Guest without a paypal account.

For others it offers the Checkout as a Guest button but after entering the credit card it also requires an username and password in order to create an account.

For others it just simply does not offer the Checkout as a guest feature.

All of those users use the same website, with the same settings enabled (Express Checkout)

If the clients access the shop from a desktop device then it redirects them to websc&cmd=_express-checkout

If they are from mobile it redirects them to webscr&cmd=_express-checkout-mobile

The clients are from various countries from Europe and the shop is from UK.

Does PayPal have a list of policies regarding each client's country?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To set the card payment by default you must select Express Payment in the Paypal module from the backoffice. Once this is done, look for the "process.php" file in "/ modules / paypal / express_checkout" and modify line 147 (version 1.5.2) where it says:

```
$ fields ['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Login';
```

you change it for:

```
$ fields ['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Billing';
```

and payment by credit card will be the first option, without having a paypal account.